# Cannot get variable I assigned to HttpContext.User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I am creating a basic authentication system with MVC 4 that uses custom logic. I have a `UserModel` class (which inherits from `IPrincipal`) that stores data I need to be persistent. To do this I am using the following code in my Controller:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   if (userModel.IsValidUser())
   {
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userModel.Username, false);
      HttpContext.User = userModel;
      // User is now logged in; send them to Index method to load MyeMan data
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
   }
}
```

Then, in the Index action:

```
if (IsUserLoggedIn())
{
   UserModel userModel = (UserModel) HttpContext.User; // This line throws error
}
```

The error I get is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal' to
>   type 'MyProj.UserModel'.

When I look in debug, the `HttpContext.User` accepts the `UserModel` without complaint. Only when it redirects to the different action does its datatype change.

Am I doing something wrong or is this the complete wrong way to go about storing `UserModel` persisently without Sessions? Sessions will expire independently of the `AuthCookie`; I was told `HttpContext.User` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning the user will work, but this assignment will not persist between requests. You have to make sure to set up the user at the beginning of each request, perhaps in a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` or `IHttpModule`. For example, you might have logic like:

- Retrieve the relevant cookie from the request
- Verify that the cookie corresponds to a valid session (e. g. by querying a database containing this information)
- Retrieve the session information based on the cookie and store it in the User property

Also, when you assign `HttpContext.Current.User` consider assigning `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` as well.

Comment: Thanks. Reading further I see that HttpContext will not persist between calls to the Controller. I have found MVC4 very frustrating for this, complicating a simple task when it exists to simplify the development process. I'm going to go for a crappy Session implementation because this is proving a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Read **[<kbd>Passing Data in an ASP.NET MVC Application</kbd>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

You can use `TempData` to pass the data between the action. It will be available for only subsequent requests

```
  TempData["User"] = userModel;
  // User is now logged in; send them to Index method to load MyeMan data
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
```

In Index

```
 UserModel user= (UserModel)TempData["User"];
```